# properly convert Audio 5.1 on PRORES Video to Stereo audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to extract a prores video with just 2.0 (with L R on same track) from a Prores with the below audio track layout. I ran the command below which converted the 5.1 to 2.0 audio/video, but the audio is unusable, dialog is missing when compared to source video. Can you advise how to properly convert the 5.1 audio to stereo.

Desired Output PRORES to contain below track layout

track 0 - video (src Stream #0:0) track 1 - L R (src Stream #0:1)

Command I ran

```
ffmpeg -i source.mov -ac 2 -c:v copy ouput.mov
```

Below is the source video/audio Track Layout

Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (HQ) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 171944 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23976 tbn, 23976 tbc (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 HQ

Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FL), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler

Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FR), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler

Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler

Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (LFE), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler

Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (BL), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler

Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (BR), s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler

Stream #0:7(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, downmix, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2019-05-21T01:26:51.000000Z
handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler

Stream #0:8(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2020-03-17T19:58:52.000000Z
handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
reel_name       :
timecode        : 00:00:00:00

Comment: The downmix track should have it. Use the 2nd command in my answer in your last Q.

Answer (score -1):

Dialogs may be in LFE channel. Look at the image below. As you can see, LFE channel is not imported. Try this command:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mov -af "pan=stereo|c0=FL+FC+BL|c1=FR+BR+FC+LFE" stereo.mov
```

[image: 5.1 → stereo]

For more information, read this doc:
[Manipulating audio channels](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#a5.1stereo)

Comment: LFE is Bass, meant to be sent to a subwoofer.